# Did anyone manage to use Mobile App Events?

Tags: mobilepush

Our MC org has been rolled out with the App Event Feature, which allows to register events and their attributes in MC :

[image: So we create definitions]

Then, we can call them directly from the App with a very simple call. No arg event call in Kotlin here :

```
val event = com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.components.events.EventManager.customEvent("First Buy")
SFMCSdk.track(event)
```

On MC side, we have a journey which Entry is a such an event.
Logs show activity but the journey keeps empty.

So, before we further investigate, I wonder : Did anyone manage to use Mobile App Events ?

Of course, we have the workaround of using standard events, which works fine, but we'd like to test this native feature. No luck so far.

Many thanks in advance !

F.

Comment: Open a support ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same experience and contacted MC support which answered the rollout of Mobile App Events had been suspended due to a known bug, with no fixing ETA. So, unfortunately, our advice is to *not* use it yet.

Comment: Thanks, we'll stick back to good old events until a fix is raised.

Comment: You should open a support request. It creates visibility and pressure for a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Keep up with classical event until it's released.

Comment: Yes, definitely sounds the safest bet as of now